# not enough values in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**can anyone fix code below, i try to create new datatype because %rowtype can only apply for one table
but 'emp' variable has store value of 2 table**

```
--Write a stored procedure (with EmpNo parameter) to print out employee’s name, employee’s email address and department’s name of employee that has been out.

CREATE TYPE emp_type AS OBJECT (
  empname        nvarchar2(10),
  email       nVARCHAR2(10),
  deptname     nvarchar2(20));
CREATE  or replace PROCEDURE print_emp_out
       (var_empno in int)
      IS
      emp emp_type;
      BEGIN
          SELECT e.empname,e.email,d.deptname into emp
          FROM employee e join department d on e.deptno=d.deptno
          where e.empno=var_empno and e.status=2;
      END;
```

Comment: What is the problem?  What do you want the code to do?  What does the data look like?

Comment: -Write a stored procedure (with EmpNo parameter) to print out employee’s name(emp table), employee’s  email address (emp table)and department’s name(department table) of employee that has been out.

Comment: You construct an `emp_type` object using `emp_type(empname, email, deptname)`, not what you have in your `select into` But I agree with other comments that involving object types overcomplicates the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's *maybe* too complex (declaring a separate type).

A simple option is to create a cursor for loop which will - true - execute only once, but will save you of declaring variable(s) which will accept data `select` returns. Moreover, it is safe from the `no_data_found` or `too_many_rows` errors as it'll just return *nothing* or display as many rows as `select` returns (should be just one row, unless more than a single employee share the same ID).

Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema. Rewrite it so that it works on your tables.

```
SQL>   set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure print_emp_out (var_empno in int)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select e.ename, e.job, d.dname
  5                  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  6                  where e.empno = var_empno
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||' ' || cur_r.job ||' '|| cur_r.dname);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec print_emp_out(7369);
SMITH CLERK RESEARCH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting `emp` to a `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `OUT` type parameter for the Procedure might be more resilient, and straightforward such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_emp_out( var_empno INT, emp OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) IS
BEGIN
  OPEN emp FOR
  SELECT e.empname, e.email, d.deptname
    FROM employee e
    JOIN department d
      ON e.deptno = d.deptno
   WHERE e.empno = var_empno
     AND e.status = 2;
END;
/
```

and then call from *SQL Developer*'s console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    res SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    print_emp_out( 7777, :res );
END;
/

SQL> PRINT res;
```